# Asp.NET MVC FileSystemWatcher does not work after close browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, filesystemwatcher

I created file system watcher in my mvc application. But there is one problem: when client closes browser and leave application for a long time file system watcher stops working. File watcher monitores a ftp directory, everyday at roughly 23:58 or 00-00 data refreshes. Here is the code of file system watcher and Global.asax.cs:
MonitorConfig.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using KegokProj.Models;
using KegokProj.BLL;
using System.Web.Hosting;

namespace KegokProj.App_Start
{
    public class MonitorConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterWatchers()
        {
            var fileWatcher = FileWatcher.ObserveFolderChanges(@"F:\ftp\data", "*.txt", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
            .Subscribe(fce =>
            {
                if (fce != null)
                    RecordEntry(fce.FileName);
            });
        }

        private static void RecordEntry(string fileName)
        {
            BLogic bll = new BLogic();
            bll.AddParamsByFileWatcher(fileName);
        }
    }
}
```

Global.asax.cs:

```
using FluentScheduler;
using KegokProj.App_Start;
using KegokProj.BLL;
using KegokProj.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.SessionState;

namespace KegokProj
{
    public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication, IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            MonitorConfig.RegisterWatchers();
        }
    }
}
```

FileWatcher class:

```
using KegokProj.BLL;
using KegokProj.Controllers;
using KegokProj.DAL;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Hosting;

namespace KegokProj.Models
{
    public class FileWatcher
    {
        public class FileChangedEvent
        {
            public string FullPath { get; private set; }
            public string FileName { get; private set; }
            public bool IsFileDeleted { get; private set; }
            public bool IsFileChanged { get; private set; }

            public FileChangedEvent(string path, string fileName, bool isFileDeleted = false, bool isFileChanged = false)
            {
                FullPath = path;
                FileName = fileName;
                IsFileDeleted = isFileDeleted;
                IsFileChanged = isFileChanged;
            }
        }

        public static IObservable<FileChangedEvent> ObserveFolderChanges(string path, string filter, TimeSpan throttle)
        {
            return Observable.Using(
                () => new FileSystemWatcher(path, filter) { EnableRaisingEvents = true },
                fileSystemWatcher => CreateSources(fileSystemWatcher)
                    .Merge()
                    .GroupBy(c => c.FullPath)
                    .SelectMany(fileEvents => fileEvents
                        .Throttle(throttle)
                        .Where(e => !e.IsFileChanged)));
        }

        private static IObservable<FileChangedEvent>[] CreateSources(FileSystemWatcher fileWatcher)
        {
            return new[]
            {
            Observable.FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs >(handler => fileWatcher.Created += handler, handler => fileWatcher.Created -= handler)
                        .Select(ev => new FileChangedEvent(ev.EventArgs.FullPath, ev.EventArgs.Name)),

            Observable.FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs >(handler => fileWatcher.Deleted += handler, handler => fileWatcher.Deleted -= handler)
                        .Select(ev => new FileChangedEvent(ev.EventArgs.FullPath, ev.EventArgs.Name, true)),

            Observable.FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs >(handler => fileWatcher.Changed += handler, handler => fileWatcher.Changed -= handler)
                        .Select(ev => new FileChangedEvent(ev.EventArgs.FullPath, ev.EventArgs.Name)),

            //The rename source needs to send a delete event for the old file name.
            //Observable.Create<FileChangedEvent>(nameChangedObserver =>
            //{
            //    return Observable.FromEventPattern<RenamedEventHandler, RenamedEventArgs>(handler => fileWatcher.Renamed += handler, handler => fileWatcher.Renamed -= handler)
            //        .Subscribe(ev =>
            //        {
            //            nameChangedObserver.OnNext(new FileChangedEvent(ev.EventArgs.FullPath, ev.EventArgs.Name));
            //            nameChangedObserver.OnNext(new FileChangedEvent(ev.EventArgs.OldFullPath, ev.EventArgs.Name, true));
            //        });
            //}),

            Observable.FromEventPattern<ErrorEventHandler, ErrorEventArgs >(handler => fileWatcher.Error += handler, handler => fileWatcher.Error -= handler)
                        .SelectMany(ev => Observable.Throw<FileChangedEvent>(ev.EventArgs.GetException()))
        };
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to host your filesystem watcher in a Windows Server or in an IIS Always-on website. IIS will automatically close your application pool thread, or create new parallel ones if the load requires it.

IIS Application Pool recycling reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling/

Comment: I already checked the session timeout in ASP settings of IIS services manager. There are two places in settings where i can edit this option and i set both of them to 1 minute, so i left for a 1 minute my website. Then i tried to check filesystemwatcher but it still works for 20 minutes.

Comment: Its not the ASP.net Session timeout but the IIS application pool timeout. The Windows Thread that your IIS application runs under is regularly torn down and recreated by IIS - and it may be that more than one thread is created for your app if under pressure. Your site should not assume any continuity between user-created calls.

Comment: Yes, i did it. I mean that edited IIS app pool idle timeout and set it to 0. Then set "the process mode=alwaysrunning" option in applicationHost.config. So it helped me. But! I found another problem with memory usage. For example when i opened and closed my website it still used to consume 70 Mbs memory.

Comment: So how i should solve it? It proceeds using more and more RAM 
 memory which displayed in Task Manager

Comment: @LifanSolano sorry to be unhelpful, but your quesiton has now been answered, please accept the answer (or not, as you see fit). If you identify some poorly performing code in your website that continues to consume memory, using the standard VS.net Profiling tools then feel free to post a new question asking for help in solving that problem.

Comment: Once again I convinced in " developers' " skill. I just asked how i can solve my ASP.NET problem and they answered me "it is very easy and simplified". Thanks for Your help. What would I do without Your advices.